# Cannot cast ufunc subtract output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind' despite forced convertion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, casting, arima

I have a data Series `ts`:

```
0    2599.0
1    2599.0
2    3998.0
3    3998.0
4    1299.0
5    1499.0
6    1499.0
7    2997.5
8     749.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

and I would like to predict the next period using ARIMA:

```
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt

array = []

for i, row in test.iterrows():
  print("row['shop_id']: ", row['shop_id'], " row['item_id']: ", row['item_id'])
  ts = pd.DataFrame(sales_monthly.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, [row['shop_id']],[row['item_id']]], :]['item_price'].values*sales_monthly.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, [row['shop_id']],[row['item_id']]], :]['item_cnt_day'].values).T.iloc[0]
  rng = range(5)
  for i in rng:
    for j in rng:
      try:
        tmp_mdl = smt.ARMA(ts, order = (i, j)).fit(method='mle', trand='nc')
        tmp_aic = tmp_mdl.aic
        if tmp_aic < best_aic:
          best_aic = tmp_aic
          best_order = (i, j)
          best_mdl = tmp_mdl
      except:
        continue
  if best_mdl.predict()<0:
    y_pred = 0
  else:
    y_pred = best_mdl.predict()
  d = {'id':row['ID'], 'item_cnt_month': y_pred}
  array.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df
```

But I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-85dfa2fa67c1> in <module>()
     22       except:
     23         continue
---> 24   if best_mdl.predict()<0:
     25     y_pred = 0
     26   else:

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in geterrors(self, params)
    686             k = self.k_exog + self.k_trend
    687             if k > 0:
--> 688                 y -= dot(self.exog, params[:k])
    689 
    690             k_ar = self.k_ar

UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'subtract' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

So I used `best_mdl.predict().astype('float32')` but it didn't changed anything.